# I'm using document.querySelector() and logging to the google Chrome Console. The output seems buggy and advice would be appreciated

Tags: google-chrome, console.log, queryselector

When I console log the following in Google Chrome:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('#task-title'));
```

The output in the console should look like this:

```
<h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
```

But more offten than not it displays like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50BIa.png)

If I click refresh about 10 times I eventually get the correct output.

Can someone tell me why this is and if there is a way to fix it?

It seems like some kind of bug to me.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, it is correctly logging h5 with the id, and all of the properties that belong to that h5.  It's just not written in html syntax

Comment: Thanks, the browser behaviour is a little inconsistent.  I can see that the snippet is in the outerHTML property. There's just a lot off noise around it.  I can add .outerHTML at the end of the query selector to remove all the noise I guess.